# Function that's nowhere equal to its derivative

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, functions, derivatives, soft-question

I am interested in finding complex, differentiable, non-constant functions that are nowhere equal to their derivatives. That is, I want to find functions $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C},$ such that there exists no $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z_0)=f'(z_0).$

Initially, I was looking for real functions with this property and found one fairly quickly. $f(x)=x^2+2$ is never equal to its derivative for $x\in\mathbb{R}.$

However, I haven't been able to find such a complex function. Any help in finding such a function would be appreciated.

Comment: $e^z+1$ for example.

Comment: to generalize @lulu's comment, all functions of the form $ae^z + c$ work, where a and c are non-zero constants.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In essence, you want that $g(z)=f(z) - f'(z) \not=0$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.
Well, there is one such function, for example $g(z)=e^z$ is non-zero for all complex $z$. You could also use a constant function instead, for example $g(z)=1$.

Assume the case with $e^z$, so we want to solve the following differential equation $(y=f, z=x)$
$$
y - y' = e^x.
$$

It's not hard to show that the solutions are of type
$$
y = ce^x - xe^x
$$

Therefore $f(z) = ce^z - ze^z$ for any $c\in\mathbb{C}$.
Note that these are not all solutions, just a subset.
As noted in the comments, $f=ce^z+a$ is a solution for the equation $f-f'=a$.

---

A complete characterisation of these functions is as follows.
Let $h(z)$ be any holomorphic function. Then a solution of
$$
f - f' = e^h
$$
satisfies the required property.

On the other side, let $f$ be such a function, and let $f-f'=g(z)$.
Since $g(z)\not=0$ in $\mathbb{C}$, there is a logarithm of $g$ denoted as $h=\log(g)$. Then
$$
f-f' = g = e^{\log(g)}=e^h.
$$
It is important that we consider functions on whole $\mathbb{C}$ and not some subset (simply connected subset also works), because the existence of the logarithm in that case is not guaranteed. For example $g(z)=z$ on $\mathbb{C}^*$ does not have a holomorphic logarithm.

Given any holomorphic $h(z)$, the solution to the above differential equation is
$$
f(z) = -e^z\int_0^z e^{h(t)-t}\ dt + ce^z.
$$